Make self contained Tables in R similiar frmttable Command
I usually used Stata for creating self-contained tables to frmttable.  What would be the command or similar package that would allow me to create self-contained tables with a good degree of customization in R?
I leave this paper as a reference:
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200406

How about gt? C.f. https://gt.rstudio.com/.
